# Block other threads from executing a statement block while current thread is executing it

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I want to block all the other threads from executing until `SendReceive(Socket, strXmlFormat)` function has finished its execution,as it is used to send data over the socket and manually closes the connection. As per the requirement when the data is sent to the server ,no other data has to be sent to it until the connection is closed manually by simply sending a flag to the server. So what i want is that all other threads that are running the process should stop until this block of code has finished execution.

```
process(int start, int end)
{
   // Block other threads from executing while the current thread executes this code block
   Socket = Connect(strSMSIP, strSMSPort);
   SendReceive(Socket, strXmlFormat);
  // undo blocking the threads  
}
```

This is how the threads are created and the process is assigned to it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   int start = i+10
   int end=start+10;

    new Thread(delegate()
    {
        Process(start, end);
    }).Start();
 }
```

Comment: `per the requirement when the data is sent to the server ,no other data has to be sent to it until` that will be hard to achieve in the presence of multiple clients, possibly even distributed among multiple machines. A simple `lock` or even machine wide `Mutex` will not help. You would be better of to enforce this requirement on your server, if at all.

Comment: @Christian.K this process will run on one machine only.

Comment: OK, then if there is only a single instance _ever_ of that process, than look at @Jakub Lortz's answer. Otherwise look into the [`Mutex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx) class to synchronize multiple processes.

Comment: @Christian.K Its an exe file that would be run by the scheduler on one server only but would the solution work if multiple threads are executing the same process??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`lock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) statement

> The lock keyword ensures that one thread does not enter a critical section of code while another thread is in the critical section. If another thread tries to enter a locked code, it will wait, block, until the object is released.

```
private object _lockObject = new object();
public void Process(int start, int end)
{
    lock (_lockObject)
    {
        Socket = Connect(strSMSIP, strSMSPort);
        SendReceive(Socket, strXmlFormat);
    }
}
```

Note that it will only synchronize threads of one process.

If your clients can run in several processes on one machine you could use a named [mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Named system mutexes are visible throughout the operating system, and can be used to synchronize the activities of processes. You can create a Mutex object that represents a named system mutex by using a constructor that accepts a name.

```
private Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "Name");
public void Process(int start, int end)
{
    try
    {
        mutex.WaitOne();
        Socket = Connect(strSMSIP, strSMSPort);
        SendReceive(Socket, strXmlFormat);
    }
    finally
    {
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

Comment: Its an exe file that would be run by the scheduler on one server only but would the solution work if multiple threads are executing the same process?? See i can't test the code after writing it due to some reasons, so i'll have to trust your solution blindly.

Comment: @psyLogic In that case you might combine both solutions - use a named mutex to make sure there is only one instance of your application running at a time, and use `lock` to synchronize threads.

Comment: Okay thank you! I will mark the answer correct after a while when its confirmed so bear with me a little.